# A Few Tile Problem?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Have designed a number of puzzles - would love to know what you thought?

From the four tiles which two are A and B?

[image]

Comment: While we will solve puzzles that you make (thank you for contributing a puzzle to our collection!) and answerers may provide some general feedback, the main question cannot be "what do you think?" because that's fundamentally subjective and opinion-based. Once you get 20 reputation, join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) for more freeform discussion

Comment: @bobble I am pretty sure that people with less than 20 points can engage in chat on their own posts.

Comment: @VarunW. there's an exception for *commenting* on your own posts, but chatting is only linked to a specific site

Comment: @bobble My bad I got chat and comment mixed up. I just saw the link.

Answer (score 2):

Potential solution:

> US and GENERAL go in circle 'A'
>  REVIEWS and SERGEANT go in circle 'B'

Reasoning:

> "Few tile" is a pun for 'futile', but if anything, it connotates the game Scrabble, implying we could try to look to the letters for a solution.

> "Rank and File" implies the order and position of the letters is relevant.  Feedback: This is on theme with General and Sergeant, which is good.

> "EU" seems to primarily clue 'European Union', which seems meaningless; feedback: nice red herring.  Second possibility is it indicates we should be looking at vowels.

> All four words contain at least one 'E' and 'U', so their mere presence is not sufficient to categorize. Going back to 'rank and file', and the fact that the left circle has one ? above it, and the right circle has two ??'s above it, let's look at the adjacent vowels in the words, similar to how "EU" is composed of only two adjacent vowels.

> It is seen that two words, US and GENERAL contain sets of one single vowel.  REVIEWS and SERGEANT contain sets of both single vowels and adjacent vowels, which would indeed put them in the center "union" area for words with both single vowels and adjacent vowels.  "EU" has only adjacent vowels, so it is in the rightmost circle on its own.

Thus,

> US and GENERAL go in circle 'A'
>  REVIEWS and SERGEANT go in circle 'B'

Feedback:
If this is not the solution, then the puzzle may have too many solutions and not enough data.
If this is the solution, then it was a fun little puzzle and I enjoyed it. Keep on puzzling!

Comment: Thanks Amoz - good reasoning - had not thought of that - but not what I was looking for.  I realise now I needed to be clearer in the question.   "A" is in the circle on the left, and "B" is in the intersection of the two circles.  Circles represent categories (though we do not know what they are other than "EU" is in the second one.  From the four tiles below the circles - one can be placed on "A" and the other on "B" (remaining could go somewhere else but not there).

Comment: One other thing and big mea culpa on this - which is that I tagged this puzzle with wordplay - this one really isn't - over the hundreds of puzzles of this type many are wordplay but this one could not be really characterised as such - more lateral thinking etc